# How to auto-activate python virtual environment in Visual Studio terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio, virtualenv, visual-studio-2022, python-venv

I am using Visual Studio (not Visual Studio Code) for the development of a Python application.

Is there a way to make the Visual Studio's Developer PowerShell auto-activate the virtual environment, as is possible in PyCharm or in VS-Code? Right now, I have to explicitly run the command `.\env\Scripts\activate` in the Terminal to activate the Virtual Environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a key in setting up PowerShell startup arguments.

Go to the Visual Studio 2022 **Parameters** -> **Environment** -> **Terminal**.
In "Profiles" window **click** on **PowerShell for developers (Default)**, then **Arguments** and follow next steps:

1. **Add** `-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` in the very beginning.
2. **Find** `-Command "&{ Command1; Command2; ...; CommandN}"` syntax and **add** `env\Scripts\activate` as one of the commands (so it looks like `-Command "&{ Command1; Command2; ...; env\Scripts\activate}"`).

Congrats! Now Visual Studio will activate your env every time you create PowerShell console.

**NOTE**:

`-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` setting up ExecutionPolicy only for this particular process (...that we run every time we create PowerShell console) and does NOT affect either global, user or any other env `ExecutionPolicy` variable but variable in this particular process. So it is safe to set up!

P.S. We need to change `ExecutionPolicy` to be able to run `activate` script.

**References**:

Read more about PowerShell [startup arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1) and [ExecutionPolicies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: Please excuse my grammar, i'm not a native speaker ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to work even without `-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` too.